# ¿Cómo alinear dos botones en Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Tengo este contenedor con dos botones que necesito alinear horizontalmente, es decir uno a la izquierda y el otro a la derecha.

Mi código:

```
<div class="box-header with-border col-md-12">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary manito-clic col-md-5" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalRegistrarform">
            REGISTRAR DATOS 
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success col-md-6">
            VER DATOS
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

En Bootstrap-3 puedes utilizar un `container-fluid` para deshacerte de los margenes laterales con un `row` (renglón) y a su interno colocar dos `div` con las clases `pull-right` y `pull-left` para poder hacer lo que quieres. Ejemplo:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="pull-left">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Registrar Datos</button>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Ver Datos</button>
        </div>

    </div><!--//row-->
</div><!--//container-fluid-->
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   <div class="row justify-content-between">
        <div class="col-4">
              <button class="btn btn-primary">REGISTRAR DATOS</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">VER DATOS</button>    
        </div>
   </div>
```

Prueba de esta forma. En caso que estés trabajando con Bootstrap v4.5.3 Saludos.

Comment: Creo que claramente en el título se ve que usa Bootstrap 3, igualmente en las etiquetas de la pregunta.